# Firebase Remote Config: Version condition is disabled for Unity projects

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I have a project in which I have to change remote config values of some parameters for each version. When I try to use version code while setting conditions in remote config, it is always grayed and not interact-able.

Am I missing something or is this intended? Any other ways to solve this problem other than adding a separate version control parameter by myself?

[image: Screenshot of greyed out condition selection menu]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like UI defect. After a while, i realized that "App" is a clickable button and not a section header. First click there.

Comment: I fumbled around with this for 15 minutes. (facepalm) thanks!

Comment: Jeez! That's probably the worst design snafu I've seen. I thought that "App" was a section header too!

Comment: Amazing Google :|

Comment: Same after two years !

Comment: Really confusing UI,  yet not fixed

Comment: Nice! horrible UX